# How can I create a new folder under a TFS Collection?

Tags: tfs, tfvc

We're using Team Foundation Server 2013 and Visual Studio 2017.

I'm the TFS administrator for a collection on this server.

Despite being a TFS administrator (for the collection as well as for TFS as a whole), I'm unable to create a New Folder under the root of the collection. I can only create a folder under an existing folder in the collection.

I've verified that the TFS collection root, under which I'm trying to create a new folder, is mapped to a local folder.

What am I missing? What do I need to be able to create a new folder in this TFS collection?

Comment: Solution found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862175/how-to-create-new-root-folders-in-a-team-project-source-control. If you're trying to do the same thing, please note that the answer that worked for me was Paul's answer, which was not the accepted solution.

Comment: Is not exactly duplicate because the second question not talking about open a folder under the root collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not create a new folder under the collection, you can only create a new team project there, with the team project you will get a new folder.

So go to TFS web and create a new team project or in Visual Studio in the team explorer.

**NOTE:** if you just want a new folder, create a new team project is **NOT** the solution for you. team project is completely a new and separate thing from another team project, so maybe you need to consider to create the folder ine existing project and not in the root collection.